# How to use Ajax to update RenderBody() section

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I wanted to use Ajax.ActionLink menu item but I have a problem when I call the second time the page is calling twice javascript does anyone know why?

I just wanted to update the RenderBody() after click on menu item

_Layout.cshtml:

```
 ...


<body>
    <div id="wrap">
     <!-- CABEÇALHO -->
     <div id="topo">
        <div id="topoConteudo">
            <div style="width: 100px; float: left; padding-left: 20px;">
                <img src="~/Images/logo.png" alt="Logo UNIDAX" border="0" />
            </div>
            <div style="width: 500px; float: right;">
                <section id="login" style="color: #454547; text-align: right; padding-right: 20px;">
                    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        @:  @User.Identity.Name @*@Html.ActionLink("[SAIR]", "Sair", "Usuario", null, new { @style = "color:#454547;" }) *@
                    }
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 99.7%">
            @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                @Html.Partial("Menu/_Menu")
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CORPO -->
    <div id="corpo">
        <div id="corpoConteudo">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="rodapeBottom"></div>
<!-- RODAPÉ -->
<div id="rodape">
    <div id="rodapeConteudo">
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
    </div>
</div>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

_Menu.cshtml:

```
   <li><a href="#" id="menuCadastros">Cadastros</a>
            <ul>
                <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Cartões de Crédito", "CartaoCredito", "CartaoCredito", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "corpo",   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST"}, new { })</li>
```

Controller:

```
    [CacheFilter]
    [Security]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CadastroCartaoCredito()
    {
        Session["ListaContatos"] = null;
        Session["intCartaoCreditoId"] = 0;

        return PartialView("_CadastroCartaoCredito");
    }
```

Comment: It's probably because you are returning a view that is using the same mater layout! <br/>

So, to be sure, 
Can you add the code of the `CartaoCredito` action within the `CartaoCredito` controller?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are returning a view that is using the same mater layout!

So, to be sure, Can you update your question with the code of the `CartaoCredito` action within the `CartaoCredito` controller?

Comment: I'm using the same layout for the entire system, it happens that javascript is replicating every time I give a post on the page.